# Contar elementos de un archivo.XML que contienen un texto

Tags: php, xml

Me gustaría usar PHP para mostrar sólo los elementos de un XML con el valor

```
<disponible>si</disponible>
```

Tengo un archivo .xml con el siguiente formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<libros>
    <OctavioPaz>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>no</disponible>
    </OctavioPaz>
    <JaimeSabines>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>no</disponible>
    </JaimeSabines>
    <JuanRulfo>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>si</disponible>
    </JuanRulfo>
    <JuanJoseArreola>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>no</disponible>
    </JuanJoseArreola>
    <AlfonsoReyes>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>si</disponible>
    </AlfonsoReyes>
    <MartinLuisGuzman>
         <libro>Titulo de Libro</libro>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>no</disponible>
    </MartinLuisGuzman>
</libros>
```

Uso el siguiente código para poder mostrar solo algunos nodos:

```
<?php
$xml= "./libros/lista.xml";
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$disponible = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("disponible");
$available = $disponible->length;
echo $available;
?>
```

El problema es que cuenta todos los `<disponible></disponible>` ya sea con `si` y `no`, dando como resultado: 6.

Resultado esperado:

```
Libros Disponibles ahora: 2
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Comment: Perdón me he olvidado de hacerlo, Listo, De nuevo gracias @Mariano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterando los Elementos `(Nodos)` que retorna [getElementsByTagName("nombretag")](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) , Con un `foreach`

```
$xml= "./libros/lista.xml";
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
/* Busca en el documento los Nodos con Tag = "disponible"*/
$disponible = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("disponible");
$count=0;
/* Iteramos los Nodos */
foreach ($disponible as $book) {
     /* Comparamos su valor por medio de su propiedad nodeValue
      si es igual a "si" , incrementamos el contador */
     if(($book->nodeValue)=="si") $count++;
}
/* Imprimimos la variable $count con un Texto Personalizado (el que desee)*/
echo "Libros Disponibles Ahora : " . $count;
```

Comment: Wow! Muchas gracias @Dev. Joel, esto me ha servido a la perfección y es justo lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Recorrer tu resultado en un `foreach`. De esa forma, verificarías si el contenido de la etiqueta es el que estás buscando, y ahí incementarías un contador.

En el siguiente ejemplo, usamos `$i` para ir contando la cantidad de elementos que coinciden:

```
$i=0;
foreach($disponibles as $disponible)
{
  If($disponible->disponible=="si")
   {
      $i++; //si coincidió, incrementar el contador
   }
}
echo $i; //se imprime el valor final
```

`

Comment: edité tu respuesta para agregar información sobre lo que se está realizando. Espero que sirva de ejemplo como tipo de comentarios que uno puede agregar. A veces, conviene pensar que estas respuestas muchas veces van dirigidas a alguien que recién comienza a programar, y es importante explicar lo que podría parecer obvio a un desarrollador con más experiencia.

Comment: Gracias @Desarrollador Android Jr. y @Mariano! He aprendido algo nuevo gracias a ambos, Se aprecia su ayuda!

Comment: Estamos para apoyar en lo que se pueda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para el conteo puedes hacer uso de XPath y la función count. Mira la solución que le han dado en esta [otra consulta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

Por otro lado, si tienes control sobre el proceso de generación del XML, te recomendaría que lo "normalizaras", porque tal y como está se complica un poco su procesamiento...
Para cada libro, te propongo una estructura del tipo:

```
 <libro>
         <titulo>Titulo de Libro</titulo>
         <autor>JuanRulfo</autor>
         <anio>Year</anio>
         <formato>.ebook</formato>
         <disponible>si</disponible>
    </libro>
```

Con esta estructura podrías recuperar fácilmente todos los libros cuyo elemento "disponible" tenga un valor determinado: 
 XPath: `//libro[./displonible = 'si']`

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo, en enlace que me has compartido me ha dado ideas sobre como normalizar mejor mi archivo, Muchas gracias!